# Problem with auto increment primary key (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have 2 tables each using other's primary key as a foreign key. The primary keys for both are set to `auto_increment`.

The problem is, when I try to create and entry into one of the tables, I have no idea what the primary key of the entry is and can't figure out what to put in the other table as a foreign key. What should I do? Do I drop auto_increment altogether and cook up a unique identifier for each entry so I can use it to address the created entries? I'm using PHP, if that's relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every major database going provides a means of finding the ID of the record you just inserted; the idea of auto-incremented IDs wouldn't be very useful otherwise.

In MySQL, you can use `mysql_insert_id()`.  See the [PHP function of the same name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) or the [MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/getting-unique-id.html) it wraps around.

Comment: But wouldn't it be a problem in case there's a lot of inserts being made in a very short period of time? Would it then send the id of another entry? Thanks.

Comment: If you're inserting two records and one references the other, you have to make sure they're inserted immediately after each other, or record the `mysql_insert_id()` for the first record and store it if you cannot insert the second record straight away.

Comment: mysql_insert_id() will return the last insert id per connection basis, so if you've got a lot of traffic on your site and many inserts are performed, each connection gets it's own inserted id's, there will be no problem.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the question I was asking! :)

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) can give you the value of the last generated value of an autoincrement primary key.

If you're using PDO (which you should), you can use [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead. This will work for all database systems that are supported by PDO.

Comment: Never used PDO before. Interestingly PostgreSQL has a RETURNING keyword which is pretty handy, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function: [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) in order to get the last id inserted

Answer (score 0):

After the initial insert, the [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function will return the autoincremented id value so that you can use it in the next insert